# Javascript unexpected identifier when setting variables

Tags: jquery, identifier

I was struggling with using double and single quotes for setting value in jquery.

```
$("<p><input type='radio' id='summary_text" + j + "' name='summary_text_t' value='" + resultkeys[i] + "#" + resultvalues[i] + "' /><span class='box'>" + resultvalues[i] + "</span><span><a  id='edit' href='#' onclick='edit_summary('"+resultkeys[i]+"')'><img height=15 width=15 src='assets/global/img/edit.png' style='vertical-align:top !important;'></a></span><span><a id='delete' href='#' onclick='delete_summary()'><img id='deleteimg' height=15 width=15 src='assets/global/img/delete.png' style='vertical-align:top !important;'></a></span></p>").appendTo("#summary_data");
```

This statement `throws error` for passing variables for edit_summary function.I have to pass two variables `resultkeys[i]` and `resultvalues[i]` to edit_summary function.

Comment: Which error, specifically? Do your values themselves contain quotes?

Comment: i need to pass two values eg.edit_summary('10','sample')

Comment: try this onclick='edit_summary(\'10\','"+resultkeys[i]+"')'

Comment: @AVM It throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: try adding those elements in smaller steps, so you can identify what's going wrong.

Comment: Do your values have quotes in them by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hh62upm/3/)

following should work

```
$("<p><input type='radio' id='summary_text" + "j" + "' name='summary_text_t' value='" + resultkeys[i] + "#" + resultvalues[i] + "' /><span class='box'>" + resultvalues[i] + "</span><span><a  id='edit' href='#' onclick='edit_summary(\'10\','"+resultkeys[i]+"')'><img height=15 width=15 src='assets/global/img/edit.png' style='vertical-align:top !important;'></a></span><span><a id='delete' href='#' onclick='delete_summary()'><img id='deleteimg' height=15 width=15 src='assets/global/img/delete.png' style='vertical-align:top !important;'></a></span></p>").appendTo("#summary_data");
```